# How to Project shapefile from NAD 1983 UTM Zone 12 to WGS 1984 UTM Zone 13N?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-9.3, wgs84, datum, nad83

I have a question and I have a shapefile that is in NAD UTM Zone 12 and Datum is North American Datum of 1983.

What I would liket to reprojection it to NAD 1983 UTM Zone 13N and change the Datum to WGS 84 ?

I have tried different methods but cane out the same. it seems like the Datum doesn't change, is it ?

Should it be just one step to use the project to reproject to NAD83 UTM Zone 13 ?
or is there more than just one step to get it there ?

Currently I have 9.3.1 .

Comment: To clarify - you have used the projection tool within ArcGIS to reproject your UTM12 data to UTM 13; this action succeeded without error messages, but does not seem to have any effect?

It's worth noting that NAD83 and WGS84 are very similar, and usually only differ by a matter of inches.

Comment: Yes, Using ArcGIS 9.3.1, I've use the projection tool to reproject from NAD UTM Zone 12 to NAD UTM Zone 13 but the problem Datum stated that GCS WGS 84 but the problem when you print it for my staff when they go out in the field. It becomes a problem and it will change from sphere to flat.  So you want it to change the datum to WGS as it is. Any advice ? I know I have had reproject this method from Zone 12 to Zone 13 simply but this is a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to project from **NAD83 UTM Zone 12** to **WGS84 UTM Zone 13N** (presumably you are working on/near a zone boundary).

At least in 10.1, I found **WGS 1984 UTM Zone 13N** under **Projected Coordinate Systems>UTM>WGS84>Northern Hemisphere** and  I would expect it to be found in the same location at 9.3.

So I think you should be able to do the projection you want in a single step using the **[Project](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000007m000000)** tool.

Comment: SO if I do what you said, then why is the Datum still display as  D_WGS_1984 ? Does that mean it is Datum WGS 84 ? and would that be consider sphere to flat ?

Comment: "still display as D_WGS_1984 ?" - I thought you said your input data was in datum NAD83 - output of WGS84 is as I would expect

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I  reproject it to WGS84 UTM Zone 13N and then looked at the metadata and it display as D_WGS_84.

Comment: Yes, because a projected coordinate reference system is based upon a geographic one which includes a datum. Just as if you look at the NAD83 UTM zone 12 data, you'll see it has D_North_American_1983. You have to have the gcs info to flatten the earth into plane.